# Derive or Mutate a new column based on conditions on existing columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe as shown below. I would like to derive a new column based on the existing column, based on certain conditions.

I would like achieve this preferably  using `dplyr` package.

For example: Whenever outcome value is more than one, then derive the result as 1, else 0.

```
datetime    outcome
12/1/2017   1
12/2/2017   1
12/3/2017   1
12/4/2017   2
12/5/2017   1
12/6/2017   1
12/7/2017   1
```

Expected data frame with derived variable:

```
datetime    outcome result
12/1/2017         1     0
12/2/2017         1     0
12/3/2017         1     0
12/4/2017         2     1
12/5/2017         1     0
12/6/2017         1     0
12/7/2017         1     0
```

Answer (score 2):

One way would be the following. I called your data `foo`. You want to check if each value is larger than 1 or not using a logical check. `as.numeric()` converts TRUE to 1 and FALSE to 0.

```
library(dplyr)

foo %>%
mutate(check = as.numeric(outcome > 1)) 

   datetime outcome check
1 12/1/2017       1     0
2 12/2/2017       1     0
3 12/3/2017       1     0
4 12/4/2017       2     1
5 12/5/2017       1     0
6 12/6/2017       1     0
7 12/7/2017       1     0
```

**DATA**

```
foo <- structure(list(datetime = structure(1:7, .Label = c("12/1/2017", 
"12/2/2017", "12/3/2017", "12/4/2017", "12/5/2017", "12/6/2017", 
"12/7/2017"), class = "factor"), outcome = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("datetime", "outcome"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: I'm getting this error for some reason:   could not find function "%>%"

Comment: Can you type `library(dplyr)` in your R Console? Then, you will be fine.

Comment: Similar idea: `df %>% mutate(result = (outcome > 1) + 0)`
`

Answer (score 1):

After trying some options, here is a very simple one which worked.

```
> mutate(df, v1 = ifelse( outcome > 1, 1, 0))
```